# android gradle run assemble after tests pass

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to fire off various android based gradle tasks e.g. assemble, after 'gradle clean test' is run.

Some background...

My company has jenkins and it is managed by a separate team so I don't have access to configure it myself. On any changes to the remote repo (git) a jenkins job will fire, running gradle clean test and using a build.gradle file that we have inside our repo.

I'm told that this is the only command that the build team will provide and if I want any further actions running, I'll have to configure them inside the build.gradle script.

I am imagining that I can possibly do something like afterTest(:assemble) or maybe addTestListener() but I can't seem to find any examples on google.

Can anyone here help me? Is this even possible or should I ask my build team to allow me to run a diff gradle task depending on what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring CI jobs uniformly is a good idea. However, there is no good way to have additional independent tasks executed when `gradle clean test` is run. They'd have to at least run `gradle clean build` so that you can add tasks with `build.dependsOn(myTask)`. (However, keep in mind that `build` already depends on `assemble`.) Or they run a custom task such as `gradle (clean) ciBuild` which by default only depends on `test`, and to which further task dependencies can be added as necessary.

Comment: The thing is, if they can run any one of those other commands, then they can run the one I want!! Which I'm not sure they're willing to do :( But that's good info to have for going to them with further requests, thanks.

Comment: Ok, quick question. If I can get them to run the gradle clean ciBuild how can I get that to depend on test? I've tried doing dependsOn(test) before and it says it can't find test

Comment: I believe Android projects only have an `androidTest` task. `check` will work both for Android and Java projects (but it will also run other code quality checks configured for the build, such as FindBugs).

Comment: Regarding your first comment, the point is that the build team typically wants uniform CI jobs. That's achieved by always running something like `gradle clean ciBuild` (a fixed contract), but not by running exactly the tasks that you are interested in (which will likely vary between builds/teams, and may also vary over time).

Comment: Peter, as I understand it ciBuild is a generic taskname that you have created for this example, it's not an actual gradle task? And then I can define ciBuild in my build.gradle myself? The build team have multiple diff build pipelines/setups for all the teams, inc java team, scala team and perl team. But they aren't so keen to create another one for the android team, because we use gradle they say we should just use the current gradle setup, which, from the sounds of it, I can't use (i.e. gradle clean test)

Comment: Yes, `ciBuild` is a custom task that every build would declare (typically by applying a custom plugin). Instead the predefined `build` task could be used, except that this is not as flexible (`build` already has a certain meaning, and will already depend on certain tasks).